# Why do some PHP or JS files get uploaded as one-line rather than keep formatting?

Tags: javascript, binary, uploading

I am offering zip files of a plugin I wrote with JS, PHP and CSS files for the user to upload to their server.  However, in some user cases the JS file gets uploaded as one line, obviously causing a massive FAIL and a complaint from users.  To get it working again, I just open the file and copy/paste from my properly formatted version onto theirs. Presto!  So, can someone explain what is going wrong here and how I can prevent this easy-to-fix but time consuming problem? I am using Notepad++ on Win, is there some kind of setting I should be using to save my files? Or is it a remote server problem that I just can't prevent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by different [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) and their interpretations on various operating systems. I would thought that nowadays these problems are over, apparently not.

Ask your customer for any file created on the target system and see what line ending is natively used there. Then simply give them file for the target platform (AFAIR Notepadd++ allows you to save file in with any EOL).

Comment: So there is no "catch all" for all types of system?  NP++ does convert between Win and UNIX (CR/LF) but that seems like a tiring approach...

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article I reference. It is very comprehensive and also gives examples of some conversion scripts. I am a bit surprised, typically Windows/Linux programs handle EOLs decently most of the time.